# FastAI How would I approach predicting lottery numbers using FastAI? Are there any easy tutorials? Where would I start?

Tags: prediction, fast-ai

I was working on a Keras LSTM for predicting lottery numbers in jupyter. I have a csv with the complete history of 6000 winning sets of numbers. I started using Colab to speed things up and upgraded to Pro+ but there was no difference with the upgraded processors. I came across FastAI and I have everything installed. I am completely new to FastAI and the tutorials seem complicated for serious projects.
Is there any FastAI tutorials to predict lottery numbers (6/39)?
If not how would I approach this?
What area should I focus on?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Unless the lottery is doing something very, very wrong, there will be no correlation between historical and future draws. An LSTM (or any kind of statistically-based prediction mechanism) should not be expected to provide any advantage.

Answer (score 0):

FastAI is great at supporting easy out-of-the-box solutions for a few key problem types: namely natural text, image, tabular, and collaborative filtering. Your use-case is not exactly any of these, but I expect it is possible to use the [text model functionality](https://docs.fast.ai/text.learner.html#language_model_learner). [This tutorial](https://docs.fast.ai/tutorial.text.html) shows how an LSTM language model learns to predict the next word given a sentence which seems very similar to your use-case.

You will want to avoid the tokenization and numericalization steps of the text model, since you already have numerical tokens in place of words. I imagine you can get something to work either by explicitly turning those steps off or by passing in the lists as space-separated text and letting it re-tokenize/numericalize.